# Ms access - Field name beginning with number. Compile error. Expected: =

Tags: ms-access

I have a field called "1why". When I run this code

```
Me.1why.SetFocus
```

I get "Compile error. Expected: =". I'm sure it has to do with the name of my control beginning with a number, in fact if I rename it to "a1why" it works.

The most quick solution would be to rename my control however I would like to know how to fix it. I've tried putting the name between "" and () but this produces another serie of different errors.

Comment: An alternative to brackets is `Me("1why").SetFocus`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can fix, it would be with brackets:

```
Me![1why].SetFocus
```

But do rename it anyway.

Comment: It is obviously a bad practice in many environments to begin a control's name with number. But what baffles me is that MS don't officially discourages users to do it ( [Guidelines for naming fields, controls, and objects](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-for-naming-fields-controls-and-objects-120c27fa-7ae1-4182-9baa-dbd183179cc3) ) while it clearly causes issues like here

Comment: Doesn't work. I've renamed the control. Thanks, @Gustav.